# Synchronizing results with *Map drag and zoom?

Tags: google-maps

I have just joined stackoverflow, but I have read through multiple threads and several articles before posting my question here.
We are currently using Google Maps V2 (the migration to V3 will be after launched because time is crucial at the moment).

**Process**: When a user comes to the site, we detect their city and we have the Map centered around it.  Similar to how it would be if you visit Yelp and browse a specific city.  A full physical address is associated with each item/result, so if applicable, the user would see 'results' on his local map.

**Problem:** We are unable to "synchronize" the results with the *Map screen*.  It should be in such a way that when a user zooms in, or drags the map -- that the listings update accordingly.  But what's actually happening is that the results are being updated by Zip Code, so this consequently displays results that outside of the map screen.
I found several threads about this issue on V3, and even saw some solutions but they do not apply to V2.  I wish our developer had more knowledge on Google Maps, he completed the rest of the site quite well!

Any input on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Since you wrote "I wish our developer had more knowledge on Google Maps" I assume you're not a developer, so I'd suggest that you let your developer do the talking here, since this is a site for developers. 2. The solution to your problem is rather simple, but if you already read multiple threads and articles and haven't found out how to do it, it is most likely that you won't understand the answer here either, because you're not a developer. Again, I'd suggest you let your developer do the talking here.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time Marcelo.  What I meant by that statement was that the "developer" made the rest of the site but lacks knowledge in Google Maps, so I have done everything myself.  This is why I took it to the public forums to ask for help, since after reading v3 articles, I could not find the solution.  I would really appreciate some references or resources so I can read up on it more to solve the problem, and if it's as simple as you mention, then even the solution itself would be great.  I'm just in stump, hope someone can help.  Thank you again for the response Marcelo!

Comment: I'm confused now. Are you looking for a solution for V2 or V3? Either way, you need to add event listeners that will send an AJAX call to refresh the data when the user has interacted with the map, only that the syntax is different depending on the version (V2 or V3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mashup has the same functionality you're looking for, and it's V2:

http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/

See the lines:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", moveEnd);
GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", zoomEnd);
```

They add the event listeners and they call the functions moveEnd and zoomEnd. Then those functions get the new position information and call function doSearch() which in turn sends an AJAX call to the server to get new data.

Comment: That was of great help, thank you so much Marcelo!  It seems to be functioning well now, I appreciate your time.